# Excluding pattern in regular expression search and replace

Tags: regex, perl

I have this string

```
asp.net somedomain.com
```

I need to strip out the domain dot extension part only except in certain cases. So I want this:

```
asp.net somedomain
```

Any time there is vb.net, asp.net etc.. I do not want to strip out the extension.

I tried this in perl with no effect.

```
$company =~ s/(?=\w+)(?!=asp|vb|c#)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\b/\1/g;
```

My logic is stuff before the dot must be one or more alpha and not `asp` or `vb` or `c#`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Negative LookBehind. You were almost there, but using LookAheads.

RegExp: `(?<!asp|vb|c\#)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\b`
Replace with nothing

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/tG5rO1

To workaround the variable length RegEx error use this: `(?<!asp)(?<!vb|c\#)\.[a-z]{2,6}\b`
*Edit: separate LookBehind group for different length excluded word*

This will only find TLD's that don't match your criteria.

**Update:**

*To take care of special cases: don't match words ending in  excluded word and match any combination of excluded word (eg. `vB` `VB` `vb` `Vb`)*

RegExp: `\b(?<!\b[aA][sS][pP])(?<!\b[vV][bB]|\b[cC]\#)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\b`
Explained demo: http://regex101.com/r/bR3kJ8

Or: `\b(?<!\basp)(?<!\bvb|\bc\#)\.[a-z]{2,6}\b`
When used with `case insensitive` RegEx modifier **i**

**Update #2**

Safer as it cares only about `.net` TLD and excluded words for it:

```
/(^|\s)(?!(?:visual)?(?:basic|studio|asp|v[bs]|c\#)\.net)(\w+)(?:\.com?\.[a-z]{2}|\.[a-z]{2,6})\b/\1\2/gi
```

Needs replacement as opposed with previous variants.

Explained demo: http://regex101.com/r/kL5mQ5

Comment: I get an 'Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex..' error using the above. But this works $company =~ s/(?<!asp)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\b//g; . How can i put multiple cases int the lookbehind?

Comment: Why is it that when I add more exclusions it gives that variable length error. Now this generates the error: $company =~ s/(?<!asp)(?<!vb|c\#|basic)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\b//gi;

Comment: updated, note that in a LookBehind you can use OR only if the other word is the same length, otherwise use another lookbehind. I grouped `c#` and `vb` as the length is 2 and separated the `asp` because the length is 3

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This will meet our needs.

Comment: It will as is remove .co.uk. This is my final version. Removes all dot extensions except for microsofts .net stuff. s/(?<!asp)(?<!vb|c\#|vs)(?<!basic)(?<!studio)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\b//gi;. This does not have to be completely foolproof or need to accommodate edge cases.

Comment: yes thats better. This is what I have now: s/\b(?=[\w\.]+)(?<!\basp)(?<!\bvb|\bc\#)(?<!\bbasic)(?<!\bstudio)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\b//gi;

Answer (score 1):

Just match the last one:

```
my $s = q{asp.net somedomain.com};
my ($company) = ($s =~ / ([A-Za-z]{2,}) [.] (?:[A-Za-z]{2,}) \z /x);
print $company, "\n";
```

Or, `split` on space and dot:

```
my $s = q{asp.net somedomain.com};
my ($company) = split /[.]/, (split ' ', $s)[-1];
print $company, "\n";
```

How much work you want to put into the pattern depends on how much variation there is in your input. The examples above are based on the sample input your provided.